# Double sum of mixed terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

I have a double sum given by

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1,\ j\neq i}^n x_i\cdot x_j = 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i}x_i\cdot x_j, $$

where the equality supposedly stems from the fact that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i} x_i\cdot x_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i} x_i\cdot x_j. $$

I see how the first equation follows from the second, and I see why the second equation holds intuitively (e.g. by writing it down for $n=3$...).

But I cannot think of a proper proof for the second equation. Is there one or is this too "trivial" to be proven?

Comment: The summand is symmetric about the line $i=j$, so the sums on each side of that line are equal.

Comment: Just set exchange the indices, $i\rightarrow j, j\rightarrow i$.

Comment: @callculus I'm sorry I still don't get it - exchanging the indices gives me $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i<j}x_j\cdot x_i$ (for the LHS), which does not really make it any more obvious for me... :(

Comment: just a comment on mathjax: alternatively you can use the command `\substack{A\\B\\...\\D}` inside a subindex to stack the elements `A`,`B`,...,`D` vertically, by example $$\int_{\substack{A=1\\B\neq 1}}$$

Comment: @Bernd Yes, it shows that the condition $x_i=x_j$ must hold for your second equation. Thus it´s not useful for your first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following representation might be helpful.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\ne i}}^nx_ix_j}
> &=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j+\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}x_ix_j\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}x_jx_i+\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}x_ix_j\\
> &=2\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}x_ix_j\\
> &\color{blue}{=2\sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_ix_j}\\
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* In the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i}x_ix_j$ is the inner sum with entry  $i=1$ an *empty sum* equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ let $A=(a_{ij})$ denote the square matrix defined by $a_{ij}=x_i\cdot x_j$.

Then $A$ is a symmetric matrix. So the sum of the terms below the main diagonal equals the sum of the terms above the main diagonal.

That is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i} x_i\cdot x_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i} x_i\cdot x_j. $$

Answer (score 1):

Use mathematical induction.

The inductive step goes like this :

$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{j<i} x_i x_j &=& \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{j<i} x_i x_j + x_{n+1} \sum\limits_{j<n+1} x_j \\
& = & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{n \geq j>i} x_i x_j + x_{n+1} \sum\limits_{j<n+1} x_j \\
& = & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{j>i} x_i x_j 
\end{array}
$

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you!